# ng-View not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new in angular JS and ng-view is not working.

Below is code of AngularFormsApp.js

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp', ["ngRoute"]);

angularFormsApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "app/Home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"

})
.when("/newEOIForm", {

    templateUrl: "app/EOIForm/eoifTemplate.html",
    controller: "eoifController"

})
.otherwise({

    redirectTo: "/Home"
});
});

angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.addNewEOI = function () {
        $location.path('/newEOIForm');

    };
});
```

Below is html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularFormsApp">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
<script src="app/EOIForm/eoifController.js"></script>
<script src="app/EOIForm/eoifDirective.js"></script>
<script src="app/EOIForm/eoifService.js"></script>


</head>
 <body ng-controller="eoifController" class="container">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#home" class="button">Home</a>
    <a href="#about" class="button">About</a>
    <a href="#detail" class="button">Detail</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

  <div class="container">
   <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Below is my root structure.

[image]

Why ng-view is not working, also I am not able to debug the code.

Comment: I kept javascript alert before $location.path('/newEOIForm'); then also alert is not firing. @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: what version of angularjs are you using? you might need to change `href="#home"` to `href="#!home"`

Comment: i am using AngularJS v1.6.10, where should i have to keep href?. @AlekseySolovey

Comment: I do not want to move from menus, i need directly calling HomeController firstly. @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: I bit confused can you post your code in below as a answer. @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: redirectTo: "/home". change case of thos

Comment: i have to remove redirectTo block?. @sridhar..

Comment: No change Home to home

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with that `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/Home'})`.

It should be:

`$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'})`

Answer (score 0):

Please, link the href in your index.html like this:

```
<a href="#home/" class="button">Home</a>
<a href="#about/" class="button">About</a>
<a href="#detail/" class="button">Detail</a>
```

And in your config:

```
angularFormsApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

// Rest of the code
```